# API for active downloads

Tags: android, api, google-play

Is there any API exposed in order to retrieve information about uploaded application in the android market?
I went through http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api but it only states the number of ratings and other stuff.
I want to know the Active downloads.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any API exposed in order to retrieve information about uploaded application in the android market?

There is no official API of any sort for the Android Market, unfortunately.

> I went through http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api but it only states the number of ratings and other stuff.

That data is pirated. Anybody using it is subject to legal action by Google.

I have [often asked for a supported and authorized API for this sort of information](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/11/07/android-market-data-empowering-bad-guys.html); Google has not done so to date.

Answer (score 0):

"That data is pirated. Anybody using it is subject to legal action by Google." - where are you getting this from? Unofficial doesn't have to automatically imply piracy.